# Capture image from a Mightex usb camera with opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to capture images from a Mightex cmos usb camera (SCE-B013-U) with Python 3.6.5 and opencv-python 3.4.3.18. The software came along confirms the camera works fine. But, `cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened()` is false. I am sure I am missing something, but I do not know what. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For testing I have 1 camera installed on my setup that I know is opencv compatible with the command below:

```
print(cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened())
```

returns True for me, but if I unplug the camera, it returns False.  False can imply that there is no camera available....
If the other answer (above) yields no result, perhaps the installed driver may not be compatible with opencv?
From the [product description:](https://secure.mightexsystems.com/pdfs/S%20Series%20USB2.0%20Monochrome%201.3MP%20CMOS.pdf)

> In addition, a user-friendly GUI based application software and an SDK
>   are provided for custom software development. A USB command set
>   protocol is also provided for non-Windows based application

Cannot help but to think that this company may be following a different standard to the one opencv typically uses.  For example, many USB3Vision cameras will not work out of the box in the way you are attempting and require additional programming to return a NumPy style array image.  
Additional support for my thinking is in the "EXAMPLE OF GRAPHICAL USER INTERFACE"
Many of the options I've seen in the GeniCam standard (USB3Vision).
Camera Mode (Continuous / Trigger), Exposure Control, Autoexposure Enable, etc

This is not to say that the camera is definitely is or is not one or the other, but the symptoms suggest the camera is not compliant to run out of the box using opencv in the way you want to.

You could try this 3rd [party SDK](http://www.ab-soft.com/products.php) instead to help verify.

I have no affiliation with them, but the ability to use their program for a (free) trial is very useful for helping to troubleshoot this issue.

Best of luck with getting your camera to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, the [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) states:

> Sometimes, `cap` may not have initialized the capture. In that case,
>   this code shows error. You can check whether it is initialized or not
>   by the method `cap.isOpened()`. If it is True, OK. Otherwise open it
>   using `cap.open()`.